# NavMeshAgent doesn't follow new recalculated path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create a path for a game object it works and it follows it, but when I create a new path it doesn't follow it. What is causing this?

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

    protected NavMeshPath path;

    void Start () {
        path = new NavMeshPath();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.SetPath(path);
    }

    public void SetNextWaypoint(Vector3 location){
        agent.ResetPath();
        agent.CalculatePath(location, path);
        agent.SetPath(path);
    }

}
```

I then have a waypoint class that looks like this (simplified):

```
public class Waypoint : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        Unit unit = other.GetComponent<Unit>();
        Vector3 next = nextTeam2.position;
        unit.SetNextWaypoint(next);
    }
}
```

The waypoint trigger is running, and so is the `SetNextWaypoint` method. However the gameobject doesn't move to the next waypoint. It goes to the first one, but once it gets there it doesn't go to the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The issues was that my next waypoint was positioned too far above the NavMesh. But for some reason `path.status` was still returning `PathComplete`.

Moving the Waypoint closer to the navmesh allowed the object to go to the next Waypoint instead of just stopping.